# How to assign every line of the file to the node of the double linked list in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a seperate a class that has this assign method, and I need to use my double linked list implementation to this class's method

```
typedef string Elem;
class A{
    private:

    public:
       method assign {
                 ifstream infile("initial_text.txt",ios::in);
                string current;
                string temp=" ";
                int count=0;
                while(getline(infile, current))
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<current.size();i++) {
                        temp+=current[i];
                        if(current[i]=='.' || current[i]=='?' || current[i]=='!') {
                            cout<<temp<<"\n";
                            count++;
                            temp="";
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                cout<<"Total Sentences: "<<count<<"\n";


}

class Node {
        public:
            Node* next;
            Node* prev;
            Elem elem;
            friend class Linkedlist;
            Node(): next(NULL), prev(NULL)
            {}
            Node(Elem elem) : elem(elem)
            {}
    };
class Linkedlist { 
    private:
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
        int N;

    public:
        Linkedlist();//
        ~Linkedlist();//


Linkedlist::Linkedlist() {
   N = 0;                  
   head = new Node;              
   tail  = new Node;
   head->next = tail;         
   tail->prev = head;
}
Linkedlist::~Linkedlist() {
    Node *current = head;
    while (current)
    {
        Node* next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}
```

For now it is just filters text file by assigning each sentence to a new line, and in this loop I need to assign it to the nodes of the linked list, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Thank you!

Comment: Please try presenting your question as if the reader does not initially know what you are talking about.  Spend more time explaining, forcing yourself to write out details. *Examples: the "separate class" is separate from what? I read "my double linked list" and thought "you have a linked list? I didn't know that."*

Comment: What you need to do is split a complicated problem into two smaller problems. Problem 1 is write some methods to add items to your linked list. At the moment the linked list has no methods so you can't do anything with it. When you have finished problem 1 (and not before) start problem 2, which is to use the methods you have written in problem 1 to add sentences to a linked list. This is how all programming works, take a complex problem and break into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```cpp
void assign() {
  ifstream infile("initial_text.txt",ios::in);
  string current;
  string temp=" ";
  int count=0;
  LinkedList list;  // create a linked list
  while(getline(infile, current))
  {
    for(int i=0;i<current.size();i++) {
      temp+=current[i];
      if(current[i]=='.' || current[i]=='?' || current[i]=='!') {
          cout<<temp<<"\n";
          // add `temp` to the end of the list
          list.add(temp);
          count++;
          temp="";
      }
    }
  }
  cout<<"Total Sentences: "<<count<<"\n";
}
```

```cpp
class Linkedlist { 
 private:
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
  int N;

 public:
  Linkedlist();//
  ~Linkedlist();//

  void add(Elem elem);  // TODO: implement this!!!

  /* These may be useful as well, but what functions you want to provide depend
   * on your application
   */
  void print();       // print entire list
  void remove(...);   // remove an element
  void at(int i);     // retrieve the element at index i
  void size() { return N; }
  // alternatively, iterator allows standard container access
  class iterator : public std::iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, Elem> {
    Node *node_;
   public:
    explicit iterator(Node *node) : node_(node) {}
    iterator& operator++() { ... }           // prefix operator, i.e. ++it
    iterator operator++(int) { ... }         // postfix operator, i.e. it++
    bool operator==(iterator other) { ... }  // equality operator, i.e. it1 == it2
    bool operator!=(iterator other) { ... }  // not equal operator, i.e. it1 != it2
    Elem& operator*() { ... }                // dereference operator, i.e. string &tmp = *it
  }
  iterator begin() { return iterator(head->next); }
  iterator end() { return iterator(tail); }
}
```

Here we've encapsulated the functionality of adding to your LinkedList so that you only have to implement it once and never have to worry about memory leaks if you do it right.  The `iterator` also provides standard c++ style bidirectional container access if you like, so that you can easily iterate through the linked list and utilize [pre-made algorithms in the STL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

```cpp
LinkedList list;
... // populate list
// print list
for (auto elem : list)
  std::cout << elem << std::endl;;
/*** STL pre-defined functions ***/
// reverse the list in place
reverse(list);
// remove duplicates in the list
auto last = std::unique(list.begin(), list.end());
list.erase(last, list.end());
// finds location of "hello" in list, or N if it is not in the list
auto index = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), "hello") - list.begin();
// count the number of elements beginning with a capital letter
int numCaps = std::count_if(list.begin(), list.end(),
                            [](int elem){ return isupper(elem[0]); });
// append newline to every element
std::for_earch(list.begin(), list.end(), [](string &elem) { elem += "\n"; });
```

Note: I didn't test this code but it should give you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: The correct approach is to add some methods to the linked list not to make private data public. If I was your teacher I would fail the above approach, since I'm not all I've done is down vote.

Comment: @john Yes you're right, I was being lazy.  I've updated my answer.